# Show only public custom posts in home page

Tags: custom-post-types, post-type

I am working on custom post types. Presently we are using below code to display all custom posts in home page

```
     <?php
$args = array(
   'public'   => true,
   '_builtin' => false
);

$output = 'names'; // names or objects, note names is the default
$operator = 'and'; // 'and' or 'or'

$post_types = get_post_types( $args, $output, $operator ); 

foreach ( $post_types  as $post_type ) {
   echo $post_type;
}

?>

<?php query_posts('post_type=$post_type'); ?>

        <?php if(have_posts()) : while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

            <?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>

        <?php endwhile; ?>

        <?php else : ?>

            <div class="page-info">
                <h1 style="font-family: <?php echo $options['heading_choise']; ?>"><?php _e('No items found', 'persona') ?></h1>
            </div>

        <?php endif; ?>
```

Am I missing anything because my home page shows `NO ITEMS FOUND`.

**EDIT 2**

Here is my present code

```
    <?php 


$query = new WP_Query('post_type=any'); 

if($query->have_posts()) : 
    while($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post(); 

        get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); 

    endwhile; 

    wp_reset_postdata();

else : 
?>

    <div class="page-info">
    <h1 style="font-family: <?php echo $options['heading_choise']; ?>"><?php _e('No items found', 'persona') ?></h1>
    </div>

<?php 
endif; 
?>
```

How to limit the output posts to public posts

Comment: Hint: If you add code to the editor, highlight it and click on the `{}` sign above the editor. This will add your code in a code block

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not to be rude, but you've missed everything here

Firstly, you should never use [`query_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts) to construct custom queries. This is not just my emphasis, but the codex as well. The one big problem with `query_posts` is, it many circumstances, pagination fails

> **Note:** This function isn't meant to be used by plugins or themes. As explained later, there are better, more performant options to alter the main query. query_posts() is overly simplistic and problematic way to modify main query of a page by replacing it with new instance of the query. It is inefficient (re-runs SQL queries) and will outright fail in some circumstances (especially often when dealing with posts pagination).

Secondly, you are on the homepage, which I believe is just a normal homepage by default. Why are you running an unnecessary custom query, when you can simply use the main query and modify that with [`pre_get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts). It is faster and also doesn't do any extra db queries.

All this said, go back to the default loop, which should be

```
<?php 
if(have_posts()) : 
    while(have_posts()) : the_post(); 

        get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); 

    endwhile; 

else : 
?>

    <div class="page-info">
    <h1 style="font-family: <?php echo $options['heading_choise']; ?>"><?php _e('No items found', 'persona') ?></h1>
    </div>

<?php 
endif; 
?>
```

Replace everything. Then use the following in your functions.php

```
function posts_on_homepage( $query ) {

    $args = array(
       'public'   => true,
       '_builtin' => false
    );

    $post_types = get_post_types( $args ); 

    if ( $query->is_main_query() && $query->is_home()) {
        $query->set( 'post_type', $post_types );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'posts_on_homepage' );
```

**EDIT 1**

I just want to add a couple of extra info here, purely for informational purposes. Was is a hurry to post as dinner was waiting :-)

I just want to come back to your code, if you had debug set to true you would have seen these problems

`$post_type` only lives inside your `foreach` loop. What you have done is to close your `foreach` before the loop, so by the time you add that to your `query_posts` arguments, `$post_type` doesn't exist anymore. So you are now passing an undefined variable to `query_posts`, causing your query to fail, and you get the *NO ITEMS FOUND* message

You should have your custom query inside your `foreach` loop for your query to work. For as long as you are in the `foreach` loop, `$post_type` exists and passes a valid value to your custom query

**EDIT 2 and 3 SCRAPPED**

**EDIT 4**

It seems that you might have a front page set, as you say my code is not working. If you have a front page set, then `pre_get_posts` won't work. Here you will need to run a custom query. Use `WP_Query` to do that. Change your query to something like

```
<?php
$args = array(
   'public'   => true,
   '_builtin' => false
);

$post_types = get_post_types( $args ); 

$query = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => $post_types )); 

if($query->have_posts()) : 
    while($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post(); 

        get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); 

    endwhile; 

    wp_reset_postdata();

else : 
?>

    <div class="page-info">
    <h1 style="font-family: <?php echo $options['heading_choise']; ?>"><?php _e('No items found', 'persona') ?></h1>
    </div>

<?php 
endif; 
?>
```

Comment: Hi pieter thanks for your reply. 
i have added the same function but i got only wordpress default post in home page

Comment: Have you set a front page or are you using a normal home page

Comment: it was set to latest posts

Comment: Check my update, it **should work**. I've tested everything. Please check and mark my answer as correct (accept it by clicking on the check mark next to my question)

Comment: thank you it works but i neeed one small modification how can i set the custom post type to public, it shows all types of post like pages, default posts and ....

Comment: updated question ..

Comment: Sorry man i am not at work for almost one month, just checked code it works. Thanks a lot for your support. how to mark your answer is correct, sorry i am little bit new here

Comment: My pleasure. To get to know how the site works, feel free to check out the [tour] page. Thanks once again. Enjoy :-)

Answer (score 1):

your `query_posts` line uses `$post_type` which will only be the last post type in the `$post_types` array.